# Exception when calling WebRTC Class, while connecting to a peer to peer Connection

Tags: swift, swift3, webrtc, apprtc, apprtcdemo

I am connecting with the signaling server using an AppRTC Peer to peer connection. I use WebRTC Framework.  All file & classes are working fine and the setup seems correct.

But when I call this webRTC class in my `videoViewController`, the application crashes with this error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString
>   key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2805b5d00'

which indicates that some value is nil, or not declared.  But I am not able to find which value is nil or not declared in AppRTC Peer to peer connection class.

Any help would be appreciated to find why.

Swift language:

```
fileprivate let audioCallConstraint = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: ["OfferToReceiveAudio" : "true"], optionalConstraints: nil)

fileprivate let videoCallConstraint = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: ["OfferToReceiveAudio" : "true", "OfferToReceiveVideo": "true"], optionalConstraints: nil)
```

Message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._NSContiguousString
>   key]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2805b5d00'

Comment: According to `https://github.com/otalk/webrtc-ios/blob/master/include/RTCMediaConstraints.h`, `mandatoryConstraints` needs to be an Array, not a Dictionary. So I guess `RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: ["OfferToReceiveAudio" : "true"], optionalConstraints: nil)` => `RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [["OfferToReceiveAudio" : "true"]], optionalConstraints: nil)` and `fileprivate let videoCallConstraint = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: [["OfferToReceiveAudio" : "true"], ["OfferToReceiveVideo": "true"]], optionalConstraints: nil)`

Comment: Rewrote much of the text, title and formatted code.